# Set permissions just for a subfolder

Tags: permissions

I have a folder under the /etc directory.
This folder and files contained in it has to be accessed by every user beloning to myGroup group.
I correctly set permissions: every file in this directory gives me, after

```
ls -l
```

> my file owner myGroup

this goes for every subfolder (I manually set this for each file/folder).

Anyway, if I type

```
cat /etc/myFolder/example.txt
```

It tells me that I don't have anough permissions.
I think this is due to the fact that /etc folder belongs to the root. But I don't want to change group to the /etc folder too! And I need that folder to stay there!

How to solve this problem?

edit:
output of

```
ls -ld /etc/myFolder/ /etc/myFolder/example.txt
```

gives me

> drwxr-xr-x 2 root myGroup 4096 feb 26 12:10 /etc/myFolder/
>
> -r-------- 1 root myGroup 1204 feb 26 12:10 /etc/myFolder/example.txt

Comment: Please add the output of `ls -ld /etc/myFolder/ /etc/myFolder/example.txt` to your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try :

```
sudo chown owner:group /etc/myFolder/ -R
```

change owner to your user and the group belong to it

```
sudo chmod 775 /etc/myFolder/ -R
```

This shold give **owner** and **group** rwx permissions.

**Note** : you can change the permission as it fits your needs .

Comment: Thanks you really helped me! Anyway I just needed r/w so my code is 664 (4 is just read for other users). If I do so I can't cd to that folder anymore, while with 774 I could...any ideas?

Comment: welcome man we are here to help each others , happy to help you and dont forget to mark it as an answer if it helped you ;)

Comment: if you can solve me this last problem I'll mark yours as answer for sure :)

Comment: try to change the owner from root to your user , why u want root to own it

Comment: i think your user is not in the group , and act as others

Comment: I discovered that +x is a permission to allow to navigate on that folder. So I manually removed the +x flag from single files, leaving the +x on the folder. I think I'll open another question if I'd like to set recursion preserving navigation

Answer (score 0):

The ownership is right. The problem is with the permissions. You have to give read, write, and or execute permissions to those subfolders.

I suggest you use:

```
chmod -R 640 /etc/myFolder
```

So your user will have read/write acces, and the users in your group will have read access.

Comment: great...after this command even cd /etc/myFolder gives me insufficient permissions...and my user is member of the group...

Comment: Maybe try 760, with your normal user, not root.